# Swift struct mutating a variable not working?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift4, mutating-function

I am not able to modify my model class variable even using `mutating func` keyword in a method?

So basically I have wrapped my problem in a very easy way I have a class `Car` that has 3 variable `id`, `start`, and `modelNo`

After that initialize an empty Car model array and then I want to show 10 cars, creating a range for loop which iterates `1...10`, initializing the Car model class and appending it to original cars array.

There is a check for first 5 cars id will be 0 and last 5 cars id will be 1

I want a filter in which same id's last car will start so I have created a method filtered and modifying the start variable but not able to modify it. Can you please help me what I am doing wrong?

Please see my complete code and copy paste it to the playground.

```
struct Car {
    var id = 0
    var start = false
    var modelNo: String

    init(start: Bool, id: Int, model: String) {
        self.start = start
        self.id = id
        self.modelNo = model
    }

    mutating func startCar(status: Bool) {
        start = status
    }
}

var arrCars:[Car] = [Car]()

for i in 1...10 {
    let md = Car(start: false, id: i <= 5 ? 0 : 1, model: "Model\(i)")
    arrCars.append(md)
}

private func filtered() {
    for item in arrCars {
        let filteredItems = arrCars.filter { $0.id == item.id }
        if filteredItems.count > 0 {
            if var lastItem = filteredItems.last {
                print("Will start \(lastItem.modelNo)")
                lastItem.startCar(status: true)
            }
        }
    }

    let cars = arrCars.filter { (car) -> Bool in
        car.start == true
    }

    print(cars.count)
}

filtered()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you `mutate` structure instance's property you actually create new instance where all but mutated property are same, and mutated is set to new value. Old instances remain unchanged, such as ones in `arrCars` array.

Comment: but I want to modify `arrCars`? how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should either replace content of `arrCars` with mutated instances. Or just use `class` here.

Comment: Replacing content is not a good approach and I will go with class for this time. Expecting some other workarounds by other. Thanks.

Comment: @matt I think my problem is something different I am talking about `mutating function `. Why did you marked it duplicate?

Comment: I don't think it is different at all. What I'm telling you is that you are thinking about this wrong. You are mutating just fine! You are just not mutating the same Car as the one in the array. See my answer below. When you understand that a struct is a value type, this is dead obvious. Thus the duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a `mutating` function on a struct doesn't change the value semantics of structs.  As soon as a struct instance is mutated, a copy is made.

You say:

```
if var lastItem = filteredItems.last {
    print("Will start \(lastItem.modelNo)")
    lastItem.startCar(status: true)
}
```

So, `lastItem` contains an instance of a car you are going to start.  Under the covers this is the same instance of the car that is in `filteredItems`, which is the same instance that is in `arrCars`. But, as soon as you mutate the `Car` in `lastItem`, a copy is made, so `lastItem` *no longer has the same instance as the one in `arrCars`*.  `filteredItems` and `arrCars` still contain the original, unaltered `Car` instance.

You can change `Car` to be a `class` rather than a `struct` so that it has reference semantics to get the behaviour you want.

The other option is to modify the instance in place; something like `arrCars[0].startCar(status: true)`.  To do this you will need to get an array containing the *indicies* of the cars you want to start rather than the cars themselves:

```
private func filtered() {
    for item in arrCars {
        let matchingIndices = arrCars.enumerated().compactMap { (index,car) in
            return car.id == item.id ? index:nil
        }
        if matchingIndices.count > 0 {
            if let lastIndex = matchingIndices.last {
                print("Will start \(arrCars[lastIndex].modelNo)")
                arrCars[lastIndex].startCar(status: true)
            }
        }
    }

    let cars = arrCars.filter { (car) -> Bool in
        car.start == true
    }

    print(cars.count)
}
```

However, where a model object requires mutability or is stateful, a struct is probably not suitable.

Comment: @user28434 in comments already said this?

Comment: Yes, they commented while I was writing an answer

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. But can you please elaborate where is a mutating function is convenient to use?

Comment: Well, you could use a mutating function in the way that you have, but you need to be aware of the structs value semantics and understand that mutating the struct won't change any other variables that hold the previous value.  You could use it to operate directly on the array as I explained, if you only used the indices rather than the instances.  To be honest, mutating functions in structs aren't very common because if you do need mutability you almost always want reference semantics

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation.

Comment: @Vishal16 - See my update for a solution that keeps the struct.

Comment: Okay, I will try.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

The answers you've gotten so far are not wrong, but they seem a little confusing. Let's look at it a little more simply. The problem is this line:

```
if var lastItem = filteredItems.last
```

This yields a Car as `lastItem`. But it is *not the same* Car as the one *in* the `filteredItems`.

That is because a struct is a *value type*. Assignment *copies* the struct. Thus, what you do to `lastItem` has no effect on what is sitting inside `filteredItems`.

So, you are *not* having any trouble mutating a struct. You are mutating `lastItem` just fine! The problem is that the `lastItem` Car is not the same object as any Car inside `filteredItems`.

Comment: Okay. I will take care of it.

Comment: While semantically you can think of the copy happening when the assignment is made, technically, the copy isn't made until the mutation occurs.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, although it's important to make clear that that is an implementation detail of Array in particular. Copy-on-write is not a fact about structs, it's a fact about certain highly optimized library types.

Comment: Probably.  I guess I was too worried about someone correcting me regarding copy-on-write in the comments :).  I should have just gone with the simplified explanation that describes the effect rather than the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to run this code and check if it solves the problem if we stick to `Structure`s. Then I'll try to explain why this helps:

```
struct Car {
    var id = 0
    var start = false
    var modelNo: String

    init(start: Bool, id: Int, model: String) {
        self.start = start
        self.id = id
        self.modelNo = model
    }

    mutating func startCar(status: Bool) {
        start = status
    }
}

var arrCars: Array<Car> = [Car]()

for i in 1...10 {
    let md = Car(start: false, id: i <= 5 ? 0 : 1, model: "Model\(i)")
    arrCars.append(md)
}

private func filtered() {
    for item in arrCars {
        let filteredItems = arrCars.filter { $0.id == item.id }
        if filteredItems.count > 0 {
            // solves the problem
            arrCars[filteredItems.count-1].startCar(status: true)
            print("Will start \(arrCars[filteredItems.count-1].modelNo)")
        }
    }

    let cars = arrCars.filter { (car) -> Bool in
        car.start == true
    }

    print(cars.count)
}

filtered()
```

Comment: No. Now there is only one car in `cars` array. I want two values last print statement will print 2 for correct output.

Comment: @Vishal16, sorry, I don't fully get the idea of code. Did you notice that before proposed changes the program prints 0. After changes it prints 1. It does necessary modification of structure.

Comment: I am just saying there are two cars which will start and In your solution only 1 car had a start.

Comment: @Vishal16, thanks for the reply. But I'm still confused. the code as I understand it is starting only last car or am I wrong?

Comment: If you run my code in Playground you will find this line `print("Will start \(lastItem.modelNo)") ` print two cars model. Please check it.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Thanks! Further answer modifications seems not needed as Paulw11 has already provided version of the code I intended to provide. The key thing per my understanding that an Array in Swift is structure by itself. And modification of it's items is possible thru the subscript `[]` operator usage. That's an interesting questions and IMHO does not duplicates attached one. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for you are feeling It's an interesting question. :)